# Convert whole number to Month-Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server, I have a column of numbers that represent the year and the month, such as:

```
YearandMonth
------------
202108  
202109   
202110
```

How do I convert this to an output like this?

```
YearandMonth
------------
Aug-2021
Sept-2021
Oct-2021
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the SQL Server 2008/2005 tags correct?

Comment: Yes it is always YYYYMM @Austin

Comment: Thanks I fixed it@Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Get the year and the month from the number.
2. Create a date from the year and the month.
3. Get the abbreviated month name from that date.
4. Concatenate month name and year.

The query:

```
select
  format(datefromparts(yearanddate / 100, yearanddate % 100, 1), 'MMM', 'en-US') +
  '-' +
  cast(yearanddate / 100 as varchar(4))
from mytable;
```

Comment: I think OP may need four-character month. Who knows?

Comment: @shawnt00: You may be right. In that case they should have a table with the month strings they want to work with (or create them ad-hoc with a values clause).

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(`yearandmonth`,'01'), '%b-%Y') as 'YearandMonth' from test_table;
```

by adding the 1st day of each month it provides the standard format so we can just use DATE_FORMAT() to get the result we need.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 this *should* work fine. Untested, of course:

```
with myTable as (
    select * from (values(202108),(202109),(202110))v(YearAndMonth)
)

select Left(DateName(month,Convert(date,Cast(YearAndMonth *100+1 as varchar(8)))),3) + '-' + Left(Cast(YearAndMonth as varchar(6)),4)
from myTable
```